# When to use copy API instead of rewrite API?

Tags: copy, google-cloud-storage

According to the [GCS documentation](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/copy),

> Generally, you should use the rewrite method instead of the copy method: the copy method uses the rewrite method, but calls it exactly once. Larger objects can require multiple rewrite calls, so copy attempts of such objects can lead to Payload too large errors.

Reading that it seems I should always be using the `rewrite` method. `copy` is a little easier to implement and it inherently limits the size of the object that can be copied, but as long as I've implemented `rewrite` anyways and I don't want GCS to limit my object size,

I'm wondering if there's any case in which using the copy method has an advantage or what scenarios should I use the `copy` method instead of `rewrite`?

Comment: Reading that it seems I should _always_ be using the `rewrite` method. `copy` is a little easier to implement and it inherently limits the size of the object that can be copied, but as long as I've implemented `rewrite` anyways and I don't want GCS to limit my object size, I'm wondering if there's any case in which using the `copy` method has an advantage?

Comment: I thiink the question has more context now. I'm deleting my comment

Answer (score 1):

**TLDR: The copy method has no advantages over the `rewrite` method.**

`copy` is meant to be used for very quick operations, or small objects, because of how it is implemented.

The `copy` REST API call has a known issue of `DEADLINE EXCEEDED` error for larger files.

For longer operations, it is recommended using [`rewrite`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/rewrite) instead of [`copy`](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/json_api/v1/objects/copy).

Comment: Sounds like `copy` can be deprecated ¯\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: I just updated my answer so that it is clearer that the copy method has no advantage over the write method.